# What does the term 'overinstallation' mean?

Tags: installation, uninstall

I came across this term [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17236_01/epm.1112/readme/epm_1112200_readme.html):

> "11882875 -- Essbase Server does not start after an overinstallation."

I know that a clean install is a software installation in which any previous version is removed. Googling 'overinstallation' turned up nothing, and I don't like to just assume it simply means 're-install'.

---

**UPDATE:**

So my understanding now is - the term "re-install" can be a bit ambiguous as it could either signify an installation after an uninstallation or otherwise. On the other hand the term "over-installation" specifically talks about installing something over an existing installation, that involved no uninstallations.

Comment: For me it sounds like a reinstall without removing the software first.

Comment: Looks like they are trying to describe the process of installing the software when its already installed.  Why they used such a strange phrase can't be explained here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The term "over-installation" refers to attempting to install something over something else, to be blunt.

For say installing Windows 7 or Vista, or Vista over XP, or 8 over 7.

Or in some cases it refers to installing something over an exact duplicate.